# Debugging Java Shaded Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm trying to debug a java-agent jar file in IntelliJ. This jar contains some shaded classes. I'm unable to debug them, since their .java files do not have same package name.

For eg. I have a class com.mypackage.MyClass, which after shading becomes com.shaded.mypackage.MyClass.

So, I opened .class file of these shaded classes in IntelliJ and set break points. But no luck, since code's line number was different in .class file , and IntelliJ sets break points to code at specified line numbers in .java file.

Any idea how to debug the shaded classes? Suggestions for other editors are welcome.

Comment: If you're using maven-shade-plugin, there's no support in debugger for this yet in idea.

Comment: Yes @GökhanPolat, I read about it on their website. So as a last hope I came to stackoverflow.